# i get date in wrong format - need help

Tags: c#, datetime

i get date from xml in this format:  `7/16/2010 (mm/dd/yyyy)`

i have in my program  `datetime val -  MyDate`.

and when i try to placing   `MyDate = Convert.ToDateTime(7/16/2010)`

i got error.

how i can fix it ?

thank's in advance

Comment: Is your code `Convert.ToDateTime(7/16/2010)` or `Convert.ToDateTime("7/16/2010")`?

Comment: On top of what Kirk asked, what is the error?

Comment: Missing exact code, error message, literal XML, good description. No response to counter questions. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime MyDate = DateTime.ParseExact("7/16/2010", "M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Be aware that the caller might want the current culture not culture invariant.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to delimit your date with double-quotes?

```
MyDate = Convert.ToDateTime("7/16/2010")
```

as it's converting from string?

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Parse("7/16/2010");

[Here is a link to the DateTime.Parse documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

Enjoy!

Comment: Be careful.  DateTime.Parse relies on the CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 0):

`MyDate = #7/16/2010#`
but first you have to switch to VB ;-)