# Problem with date type

Tags: c#, winforms

i receive this date: `9/20/2010 3:32:32 PM`

i need to convert to datetime.

i try:

```
DateTime DateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("9/20/2010 3:32:32 PM", "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but i get error: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

in my computer the region is: `Hebrew (Israel)  dd/MM/yyyy for short date and hh:mm for short time`

how to fix it ?

thank's in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [i get date in wrong  format  -  need help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721731/i-get-date-in-wrong-format-need-help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How could it work man.You are converting into "dd/MM/yyyy " & putting month as 20.In your 
question dd/M/yyyy is wrong.It will like dd/MM/yyyy.

By default format is `MM/DD/yyyy.`

simple way to do  .......

```
DateTime DateFrom = DateTime.Parse("9/20/2010 3:32:32 PM");
```

if you want to provide a specific Format so use like that

```
DateTime DateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("20/09/2010 3:32:32 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I hope it works.

Comment: @PrateekSaluja: That won't work, as it's trying to parse a date and time as just a date.

Comment: Default is only `MM/dd/yyyy` if your culture settings specify that.

Comment: Sir I tried DateTime DateFrom = DateTime.Parse("9/20/2010 3:32:32 PM"); & it gave me output.

Comment: @Prateek: Yes, I'd expect it to work now. Although it doesn't solve the actual problem, because you're not parsing the actual data he's received...

Comment: thank's it works !!!

how to show the time like this: hh:mm

(without the second)

Comment: @Gold: that's another question, I suggest raising another question (after searching for one that does not already exist) :-)

Comment: Hi try this to get time  string time=DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

Answer (score 11):

If you're receiving "9/20/2010 3:32:32 PM" as a string, then trying to parse it as if it were in the "dd/MM/yyyy" format is clearly wrong - that's try to use a *month* of 20. You're also only parsing part of the string - you need to either trim your string or provide the complete format.

Try this:

```
DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("9/20/2010 3:32:32 PM",
                                        "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that using this sort of strict parsing will only work if you can guarantee that that will *always* be the format. Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: darn you are too quick for me! Was about to post the exact same comment :-)

edit - just tested it... didn't work

Comment: it needs two 't' at the end of the format.. i.e. "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your original date string is in a US format (i.e. m/dd/yyyy). Try replacing your third parameter with `new CultureInfo("en-US")`

Comment: That's not going to help when he's explicitly expecting "dd/M/yyyy" in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("9/20/2010 3:32:32 PM", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Works for me

Comment: p.s. credit to Jon Skeet for getting there first (I just made a slight change)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use ParseExact() when I know that time string is formatted by invariant culture.

`DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

is both more compact and more clear.