# is there any way to work with date in this format: dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

is there any way to work with date in this format: `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm` (without second)

i see only this format: `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

i need that i can see in this format and to run search between date & time in this format

i work on access-2007 and C#

thank's in advance

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what it is that you need?

Comment: Date format is a present-layer issue, not a database issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [i get date in wrong  format  -  need help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721731/i-get-date-in-wrong-format-need-help). Gold, you now have posted a dozen questions about "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" and I fail to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access also has format:

```
Format(Now,"dd/mm/yyy hh:nn")
```

It can also be used in queries.

Then there are the various parts:

```
Day(Now)
Month(Now)
Year(Now)
Hour(Now)
Minute(Now)
```

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210604
And: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/format-date-and-time-values-HP001099015.aspx

Comment: ...and none of those are helpful to a C# question, as you shouldn't be formatting your dates in SQL, don't you think?

Comment: There are reasons to format a date in SQL, including when you only want part of a date.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple: add ":00" to the end of what you currently have.  For instance:

```
17/11/1985 14:56
```

becomes:

```
17/11/1985 14:56:00
```

Just do that and you should be all set.

Comment: i need exactly the opposite. i have the time with seconds and i need to get rid of the seconds

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The *DateTime* Class has a method called *Format* you can use to convert it into a formatted string.

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/